# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on bool

Tags: php, php7, xampp, php5, localhost

No entiendo, me lanza un error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\escuela_php-master\Estudiante.php:54 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\escuela_php-master\mostrar_estudiantes.php(29): Estudiante::obtener() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\escuela_php-master\Estudiante.php on line 54

El localhost esta perfectamente conectado, el problema es en la linea 54. AYUDA

Y aqui esta el código completo, porfavor ayuda

```
<?php
class Estudiante
{
    private $nombre, $grupo, $id;

    public function __construct($nombre, $grupo, $id = null)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->grupo = $grupo;
        if ($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
        }
    }

    public function guardar()
    {
        global $mysqli;
        $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO estudiantes
            (nombre, grupo)
                VALUES
                (?, ?)");
        $sentencia->bind_param("ss", $this->nombre, $this->grupo);
        $sentencia->execute();
    }

    public static function obtener()
    {
        global $mysqli;
        $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, nombre, grupo FROM estudiantes");
        return $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
    public static function obtenerUno($id)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, grupo FROM estudiantes WHERE id = ?");
        $sentencia->bind_param("i", $id);
        $sentencia->execute();
        $resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
        return $resultado->fetch_object();
    }
    public function actualizar()
    {
        global $mysqli;
        $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("update estudiantes set nombre = ?, grupo = ? where id = ?");
        $sentencia->bind_param("ssi", $this->nombre, $this->grupo, $this->id);
        $sentencia->execute();
    }

    public static function eliminar($id)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM estudiantes WHERE id = ?");
        $sentencia->bind_param("i", $id);
        $sentencia->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto te ayudará a mejorar tu pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Comúnmente es porque tu consulta tiene un error, ya sea porque no existe alguna columna o está mal escrita. Puedes ejecutar tu consulta `SELECT id, nombre, grupo FROM estudiantes` en MySQL para ver si te envía algun error de sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema de comprobación de datos:

en esta sección de tu código:

```php
    public static function obtener()
        {
            global $mysqli;
            $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, nombre, grupo FROM estudiantes");
            return $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
```

deberia validar que existen datos... en realidad es algo basico que debes hacer en todas las consultas a base de datos:

```php
    public static function obtener()
        {
            global $mysqli;
            if ($resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, nombre, grupo FROM estudiantes")){
                if(0 < $resultado->num_rows){
                    $mysqli->close(); //Importante Cerrar las Conexiones...
                    return $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                }else{
                    //Control de Error en la respuesta:
                    echo 'no se encontraron datos en la Consulta';
                    die;
                }
            }else{
                //Control de Error en el Query:
                echo 'error en la consulta a la Base de datos';
                die;
            }
        }
```

en conclusión: solo debes hacer un fetch si sabes que retornaron datos; de lo contrario tendrás errores, saltando en todos lados cuando hagas consultas.